# How to add a service implementation to mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that generally does **not** use `mvn exec:java` to be executed. But it would be nice to provide that capability for some initial setup.

I'm currently using:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="myclass"
```

The problem is that the project uses several API's that use dynamic service loading to find implementations at runtime. Hence they are not in the dependency list of the maven project but some of them are required for the `mvn exec:java` to be of any use.

How can I tell maven to use the classpath it has calculated **plus** one or more libraries that I configure?

I have tried something like:

```
-Dexec.args="-cp %classpath:/path/to/implementation.jar"
```

But this does not seem to work, any other ideas?

Comment: Was this issue resolved? Could you share the solution?

Comment: Would be curious too...

Comment: Hmm, no, I didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `additionalClasspathElements` described [here](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)